# Корзина для зарегистрироанных пользователей

Tags: php, mysql, yii2

Здравствуйте! Подскажите, пожалуйста, как сделать корзину доступной для зарегистрированных пользователей. Для корзины имеется таблица cart с полями id, book_id, user_id, count. Для таблицы user имеются поля id, login, password, fio, role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если корзина отдельная страница, можно через контроллер:

```
public function actionCart()
{
    if(!Yii::$app->user->isGuest) {
        ...
    }
    if(Yii::$app->user->isGuest){
        throw new \yii\web\HttpException(404, 'Авторизируйтесь!');
    }

    return $this->render('view');
}
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь